# Check if a Gmail draft has a specific label

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

How to know if a draft:

```
var draft = GmailApp.getDrafts()[0]; 
var msg = draft.send();
```

is member of a specific Gmail label?

I haven't found any reference to [`GmailLabel`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-label) in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-draft.

Answer (score 1):

Threads have labels, drafts do not.

Use `getMessage` to get the message associated with a draft, then use `getThread` to get the thread associated with the message, then use `getLabels` to get the labels associated with the thread.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Quentin. Just for future reference, could you add a small sample code, showing how to get the label name, as string?